# How to click off a modal to close it and properly type the event

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**I am trying to create a typescript/react modal component that closes when the close button is clicked and when the area off the modal body is clicked.** I've tried a bunch of solutions but I can't get the compiler types correct. I think the issue is my event type. I've tried Event, SyntheticEvent, MouseEvent, React.MouseEvent and a couple others. I just can't get the behavior I want with no compiler errors. Any help is appreciated.

here is a [link to a codesandbox of my issue](https://codesandbox.io/embed/0qx8v7wz4p) the example is set up to show all the compiler error messages.

```
interface State {
  isOpen: boolean;
}

class Modal extends React.Component {
  public state: State = { isOpen: true };
  public wrapperRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = React.createRef();

  public componentWillMount(): void {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.documentClickHandler);
  }
  public componentWillUnmount(): void {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.documentClickHandler);
  }

  public documentClickHandler = (event: EventListener): void => {
    console.log("doc click", event);
    console.log("ref", this.wrapperRef);
  };

  public closeModal = (): void => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };

  public render(): JSX.Element | null {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;
    return !isOpen ? null : (
      <div
        className="modal_wrapper"
        style={styles.wrapper}
        ref={this.wrapperRef}
      >
        <div className="modal_body" style={styles.body}>
          <h2>Modal</h2>
          <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: import your modal in `index.tsx` like so: `import Modal from "./Modal";`

Comment: Try this article, maybe it can help. https://medium.com/@pitipatdop/little-neat-trick-to-capture-click-outside-react-component-5604830beb7f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type is React.MouseEvent;

Which gives you the type of Reacts synthetic event.

If you have problems with event.target not being typed to what you were expecting you can do this...

```
const isElement = (something: any): something is HTMLElement => {
    return something instanceof HTMLElement;
}
```

which will allow you to do this...

```
const takeEvent = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if(isElement(e.target)) {
        // typescript will now type e.target to HTMLElement inside this block;
    }
}
```

==== EDIT =====

`instanceof` is now a recognized inbuilt type-guard in TypeScript

The more modern solution in latest version of TypeScript is.

```
const takeEvent = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (!(e.target instanceof HTMLDivElement)) return;
    const whattype = e.target; // HTMLDivElement
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestions, its working and the compiler errors are gone.  [solution link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lxn8643ypq)

Comment: please tick as answer for people who search.